# Node.js UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning

Tags: javascript, node.js, arduino

I've been trying to program this robot car to move through using Node.js but after I run the program, it gives me this error.

Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 8.9.4 (x64) and npm.

```
C:\Users\john>node 4wd.js
http://localhost:3030
(node:8660) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: Error: Opening /dev/ttyUSB0: Unknown error code 3
(node:8660) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

What does this mean? 
Does this mean it worked?

Comment: nope. its showing errors.

Comment: Please check the library/program you are using because from the directory path I understand that you use a windows machine but from the error I understand that javascript is trying to open a Unix device (/dev/ttyUSB0)

Answer (score 3):

That means that one of the `Promises` you ran were rejected - meaning that instead of resolving a value it rejected with an error.

More specifically, we can see that this is where the issue is `Error: Error: Opening /dev/ttyUSB0: Unknown error code 3`. My best guess is that your program doesn't have access to enter that directory (the USB) and therefore rejected with that error.

To prevent rejections, after your `.then` add a `catch` to handle errors.

Find out more about promises [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise).

Comment: Of course `.catch` doesn't prevent the rejection, it only provides a way to handle it. Like logging the error to the console…

Comment: Handle's the error in the sense that it doesn't get thrown into console like that is what I meant @Bergi